# Difference between child entity and value object in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've found [this great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/net-core-microservice-domain-model) where in the section on [aggregates' structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/net-core-microservice-domain-model#structure-aggregates-in-a-custom-net-standard-library), I can see a distinction being made between *child entity* (here: order item) and *value object* (here: address).

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how they differ on an architectural level. I'd like to say that both of them are value objects (aggregated within the root *Order*).

What am I missing in the picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value Objects are much "values with methods" than they are "objects".

"Address" as a value, isn't fundamentally different from a primitive like integer.  The significant difference between the two is that most generic programming languages don't come with a built in address type.  So we have to roll our own -- or re-use one from a library.

In many modern languages, you can only roll your own by using the "object" idioms to create your customized data structure and the query semantics that you want.

Value objects are data with query semantics attached.

Entities, on the other hand, change over time.  A way of thinking of an entity's implementation is that, under the covers, the entity is a mutable reference to a value.

```
void Entity::onChange(data) {
    // dereference to get the current state value
    val oldState = this.state;

    // use a pure function to compute a new state value
    val newState = stateChange(oldState, data);

    // update the reference
    this.state = newState;
}
```

The specific data structure being used to hold the state is an implementation detail of the entity of no interest to other elements in the solution.

A child entity is an entity, which is to say that it is an object with the responsibility for managing some implicit data structure.  It is designed for change.

It's "just like the root", but on a smaller scale -- the root has a more complete sense of the entire context.

See also

- [Classes vs Data Structures](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/06/16/ObjectsAndDataStructures.html) -- Robert Martin
- [Perception and Action](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/An-Introduction-to-Clojure-Time-Model/) -- Stuart Halloway